# Programacion en arduino

Tags: c, arduino

Necesito de su ayuda colegas. estoy ejecutando dos sketches en arduino. uno es ejecutar un servomotor de forma automatica y el otro es ejecutar un servomotor con un tiempo programado. el problema es que no puedo ejecutar dos tareas en un solo arduino o no se como hacerlo. soy nuevo en la programacion me muestra un mensaje redefinition of 'void setup()' por su apoyo muchas gracias el codigo es.

```
// ejecutar tarea de servomotor de forma automatica.
// Incluímos la librería para poder controlar el servo

#include <Servo.h>

// Declaramos la variable para controlar el servo
Servo servoMotor;

void setup() {
  // Iniciamos el monitor serie para mostrar el resultado
  Serial.begin(9600);

  // Iniciamos el servo para que empiece a trabajar con el pin 9
  servoMotor.attach(9);
}

void loop() {

  // Desplazamos a la posición 0º
  servoMotor.write(0);
  // Esperamos 1 segundo
  delay(60000);

  // Desplazamos a la posición 90º
  servoMotor.write(90);
  // Esperamos 1 segundo
  delay(1000);

  // Desplazamos a la posición 180º
  servoMotor.write(180);
  // Esperamos 1 segundo
  delay(1000);
}

///ejecutar servomotor con dos sensores hc-sr04

#include <NewPing.h>
#include <Servo.h>
#define TRIGGER_PIN   8
#define ECHO_PIN      7
#define TRIGGER_PIN2  10
#define ECHO_PIN2     9
#define MAX_DISTANCE 200

Servo servoAne;
NewPing ultrasonic1(TRIGGER_PIN, ECHO_PIN, MAX_DISTANCE);
NewPing ultrasonic2(TRIGGER_PIN2, ECHO_PIN2, MAX_DISTANCE);

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  servoAne.attach(6);
  servoAne.write(0);
}

void loop() {
  delay(50);
  int US1 = ultrasonic1.ping_cm();
  int US2 = ultrasonic2.ping_cm();
  Serial.print("Hasil Sensor 1 :");
  Serial.print(US1);
  Serial.print("cm     |     ");
  Serial.print("Hasil Sensor 2 :");
  Serial.print(US2);
  Serial.println("cm");

  if(US1 <= 5){
    servoAne.write(180);
    delay(500);
  }
  else if(US2 <= 5){
    servoAne.write(180);
    delay(500);
  }
  else{
    servoAne.write(0);
    delay(5);
  }

}
```

Comment: Investiga sobre freeRTOS (sistema operativo de tiempo real) te va a permitir ejecutar dos tareas en "paralelo" sin que tengas que manejarlo vos.

Comment: https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/feilipu/using-freertos-multi-tasking-in-arduino-ebc3cc   Te alcanzo un link de un proyecto para que veas como funciona, pero básicamente creas las tareas a ejecutar (funciones si querés) las agregas y sale funcionando. De manera muy simple lo que hace la librería es compartir el procesador entre las tareas que fueron cargadas. Lo he usado y funciona muy bien. En este momento estoy en un colectivo viajando, es lo máximo que puedo hacer. Ojalá te sirva!

Comment: en arduino nunca se pueden poner 2 funciones iguales esto generaria un error instantania mente ya que el programa se confundira ya que no sabra cual ejecutar bloque de codigo ejecutara
otro error que todos cometemos es declarar la librerias debajo del codigo esto generara que primero carge el programa pero no las librerias

Answer (score 1):

Debes de comprender que en Arduino como en otros lenguajes de programación no puedes tener funciones duplicadas. Para poder realizar las tareas crea una función para cada una de estas en modo secuencial, a lo que lleva a deberás de pensar de manera lineal y no paralela.

Te dejo el debate del tema de paralelo en la siguiente link  https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=51883.0

y en esta link un curso donde podrás entender un poco mas de la funcionalidad de Arduino  https://programarfacil.com/blog/arduino-blog/curso-de-arduino/

Suerte con tu proyecto.